# Create a simple array using my database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop

I have the following php code:

```
$seasons = array("Autumn", "Winter", "Spring", "Summer");
```

Now I also have a database with a table Seasons, in there the seasons like:

```
+--------+
| Season |
+--------+
| Autumn |
| Winter | 
| Spring |
| Summer |
+--------+
```

So I want to get the seasons from my database and put them in this array, but how to do that. Own attempts failed (tried using `while`, `mysql_fetch_array`, `mysql_fetch_ASSOC`,etc)

Got this for starters:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Season FROM Seasons ORDER BY Season");
```

This should give me all seasons, but I am stuck here. Searched the internet, but the examples there are way too complex for what I need...

Many thanks

Comment: `mysql_query` gives you a result set which you need to poll for rows using `mysql_fetch_*`, the PHP manual is pretty clear on this. Could you show some code you've tried but didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this bit of code. It will populate an array called $seasons with the results of your query.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Season FROM Seasons ORDER BY Season");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $season=$row['Season'];
    $seasons[] = $season;
}
```

It appears to work for me.

Answer (score 4):

```
$seasons = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Season FROM Seasons ORDER BY Season");
while($row = mysql_fetch_num($result))
  $seasons[] = row[0];
```

Comment: Dude, you're overriding $result?

Comment: Right on. You still have a typo tho :P

Comment: @Lior: o_O... Didn't see that one. Fixed now.

Comment: Hi guys, this gives me this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in etcetc` which is this part: `$seasons[] = row[0];`

Comment: @Maurice: Need more context the error does not make any sense right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo $row['Season'] . "\n";
}
```

This will loop through the results one row at a time.  When there's no rows left, `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns `false`, and exits the loop.